# SQL Server : the server principal *** is not able to access under current permissions

Tags: sql-server, security

I am trying to set-up/test SQL Server row-level security for my database. I want to use row-level security for SSRS reports and Power BI. The database is set up on my test PC using SQL Server Express with SSMS.

On my test PC I have set up a separate account -- separate from the user under which I established the SQL Server and database. I believe I have set-up the SQL Server level permissions and database level permissions appropriately(?) for the separate user.

I go into the separate user account and continually get the

> Server principal **** is not able to access under current permissions

message in SSMS and cannot access the data in the SSRS localhost website.

Is the separate user, established on the same PC, not considered to be in the same domain as the PC user who established the database? Is that what is causing the problem? If so, how can that be overcome? If not, any ideas what my problem might be? Is there some constraint in SQL Server Express that I need to establish the database using a SQL Server Developer edition?

I prefer not to wait until the database is established on the system test server to determine how this will work. Many thanks for any thoughts or suggestions.